# IS my QUBO too big for QAOA using IBM Quantum computer?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qaoa

On qiskit, I have defined a QUBO, called `qp` as follows:

```
print(qp.prettyprint())

Minimize
-1.7324559764718837*x10^2 + 0.00619189721450626*x10*x11
...
+ 3.6972673229589947*x27*x29 - 32.42658793825545*x28^2
+ 7.39453464591802*x28*x29 - 61.155908553552145*x29^2

Subject to
No constraints

Binary variables (20)
x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19 x20 x21 x22 x23 x24 x25 x26 x27 x28 x29
```

There are actually 104 lines in the minimization problem.

Using a classical solver, I can easily solve this problem:

```
cplex_optimizer = CplexOptimizer()
qubo_minimization_result = cplex_optimizer.solve(qp)
```

This gives me:

```
print("minimum point (binary): ", qubo_minimization_result.x)
minimum point (binary): [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
```

I want now to solve it using QAOA on a IBM quantum computer (QC). But before doing it on a real QC, I would like to solve it using a IBM simulator `ibmq_qasm_simulator`:

```
# Select a backend.
backend = provider.get_backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")

# QAOA parameters
number_of_shots = 100000
qaoa_reps = 1

# Betas and Gammas as described in the original QAOA paper
betas =     [0] 
gammas =    [0]

algorithm_globals.random_seed = 10598

quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(
backend,
seed_simulator=algorithm_globals.random_seed,
seed_transpiler=algorithm_globals.random_seed,
shots=number_of_shots)

qaoa_mes = QAOA(quantum_instance=quantum_instance, reps=qaoa_reps, initial_point=[*betas, *gammas])

qaoa = MinimumEigenOptimizer(qaoa_mes)  # using QAOA

qaoa_result = qaoa.solve(qp)
```

When I run this qiskit code, I never obtain a result in the sense that the code is running but never stops. Do you think my QUBO is too big for solving it on a 32-qubits IBM simulator? Should I try directly on a real 127-qubits QC?